# How to avoid blank report export to Excel in SSRS 2008 r2?

Tags: ssrs-2008

Hi I developed one report which is taking parameters dynamically with help of Data driven subscription.

but when I did subscription it is exporting all users reports into Excel and keeping it into windows file share folder.

here my issue is my client doesn't want the report if report is empty for a particular user.

but I have to fix this issue in SSRS itself instead of doing changes in Procedure (database) level.
i used the below expression in SP Level
i.e

```
if(@@rowcoun>0)
raiserror("nodata",16,1)
```

Note: but the same procedure is using for multiple purpose and my db developer is not accepting to do changes in SP levle.

in reports level i am using the below expression to hide the column headers if report is empty

```
iif(countrows()>0,"true","false")
```

but the above expression showing blank report and it is exporting empty excel sheet for the user.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using a Data Driven Subscription, what you need to do is edit the subscription query so that it creates a list of recipient emails based on those with data. The way I do this is to join the table of recipients with the dataset to be returned.

Comment: hi , i didn't get your point  , if you don't mine could you eloberate it.

Comment: What part are you stuck on? Do you know how to edit the subscription query? Do you know how to join a list of recipients with the data you want to deliver? Or are you stuck on setting the "To:" field to match a field in the query?